# Why does the accuracy of my camera drop when I start using no-ops as delays?

Tags: arduino, clock, assembly, camera

I'm using an Arduino Mega to run three TSL1401R-LF Linear Scan Cameras in parallel. I got everything working and the camera were giving me different results based on how much light was hitting them (i.e. lots of light gave me a high number and little light gave me a smaller number).

However when I attempted to increase the FPS of the cameras by reducing the delays using no-ops the accuracy fell dramatically and I have no idea why. According to the [datasheet](http://datasheet.elcodis.com/pdf/58/61/586128/tsl1401r-lf.pdf) the minimum delays for the CLK impulse is 50 ns and a no-op causes a delay of 62.5 ns so there should't be a problem. Anyone on here have and idea as to why this could be happening?

Here is my code before the no-ops:

```
void readPixels()  
{
  digitalWrite(SI, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime/2);
  digitalWrite(CLK, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime/2);
  digitalWrite(SI, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime/2);
  digitalWrite(CLK, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime);

  for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
  { 
    digitalWrite(CLK, HIGH);
    pixelsArray1[i]=analogRead(Cam1Aout);
    pixelsArray2[i]=analogRead(Cam2Aout);
    pixelsArray3[i]=analogRead(Cam3Aout);
    delayMicroseconds(delayTime);
    digitalWrite(CLK, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(delayTime);
  }

  delayMicroseconds(20);

}

OUTPUT:
Camera 1: 295, 319, 353, 387, 422, 458, 483, 499, 515, 527, 540, 545, 556, 562, 572, 575, 585, 590, 596, 598, 606, 603, 591, 589, 608, 621, 635, 636, 646, 652, 664, 670, 681, 689, 699, 705, 715, 726, 730, 734, 742, 745, 750, 752, 760, 764, 769, 766, 768, 770, 775, 777, 792, 806, 828, 852, 880, 907, 931, 956, 989, 1016, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 980, 986, 935, 935, 893, 892, 856, 847, 812, 801, 774, 760, 731, 713, 683, 647, 605, 564, 513, 470, 410, 369, 323, 289, 347, 376, 
Camera 2: 346, 368, 396, 419, 446, 462, 480, 496, 516, 531, 549, 559, 571, 579, 593, 600, 611, 619, 628, 636, 647, 651, 660, 667, 676, 679, 687, 696, 704, 710, 719, 725, 732, 735, 743, 743, 752, 758, 764, 768, 775, 777, 783, 788, 793, 798, 803, 806, 809, 814, 818, 822, 827, 831, 831, 833, 836, 839, 841, 839, 843, 843, 844, 839, 841, 836, 831, 830, 831, 830, 831, 834, 841, 847, 861, 867, 880, 894, 902, 911, 918, 935, 940, 956, 960, 976, 973, 991, 984, 1007, 998, 1020, 998, 1019, 992, 1014, 986, 997, 964, 969, 937, 937, 908, 910, 878, 875, 843, 838, 808, 797, 768, 750, 720, 696, 667, 639, 611, 582, 556, 524, 499, 471, 449, 423, 399, 371, 396, 399, 
Camera 3: 472, 491, 507, 512, 526, 551, 564, 572, 583, 588, 583, 586, 587, 593, 603, 604, 604, 608, 611, 617, 617, 621, 625, 629, 635, 641, 635, 645, 661, 668, 671, 675, 678, 680, 685, 688, 688, 690, 691, 694, 696, 701, 701, 704, 699, 706, 705, 706, 713, 715, 718, 719, 719, 719, 720, 721, 723, 731, 737, 736, 739, 743, 748, 751, 755, 758, 760, 763, 766, 768, 769, 773, 775, 777, 777, 780, 787, 791, 790, 787, 781, 779, 769, 763, 760, 758, 755, 750, 743, 741, 744, 748, 743, 740, 750, 755, 774, 783, 790, 797, 802, 810, 807, 818, 806, 807, 796, 796, 785, 777, 759, 748, 728, 715, 696, 681, 664, 647, 625, 606, 579, 558, 536, 508, 484, 467, 432, 427, 
Runetime: 2121
```

Here it is after the no-ops are added:

```
void readPixels()  
{
  digitalWrite(SI, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime/2);
  digitalWrite(CLK, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime/2);
  digitalWrite(SI, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime/2);
  digitalWrite(CLK, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime);

  for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
  { 
    digitalWrite(CLK, HIGH);
    pixelsArray1[i]=analogRead(Cam1Aout);
    pixelsArray2[i]=analogRead(Cam2Aout);
    pixelsArray3[i]=analogRead(Cam3Aout);
    __asm__("nop\n\t");
    digitalWrite(CLK, LOW);
    __asm__("nop\n\t");
  }

  delayMicroseconds(20);

}

OUTPUT:
Camera 1: 147, 141, 142, 143, 145, 145, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 146, 145, 145, 143, 145, 143, 146, 146, 145, 145, 144, 147, 147, 147, 147, 148, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 148, 147, 147, 147, 148, 147, 147, 148, 147, 151, 152, 153, 154, 156, 156, 158, 158, 159, 161, 162, 163, 165, 166, 167, 167, 168, 169, 167, 172, 174, 174, 174, 174, 175, 176, 176, 177, 177, 179, 179, 179, 179, 179, 178, 178, 176, 175, 174, 172, 172, 170, 168, 167, 165, 163, 162, 161, 159, 158, 156, 154, 155, 152, 151, 150, 148, 146, 146, 143, 143, 141, 139, 137, 135, 131, 129, 127, 125, 122, 120, 140, 172, 
Camera 2: 162, 161, 164, 164, 167, 166, 165, 167, 169, 167, 170, 171, 171, 169, 172, 171, 172, 171, 172, 172, 172, 172, 173, 172, 173, 172, 174, 173, 174, 173, 174, 174, 176, 174, 175, 170, 175, 174, 176, 175, 185, 175, 176, 175, 176, 175, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 177, 176, 177, 176, 176, 176, 177, 176, 177, 176, 177, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 175, 176, 175, 176, 176, 177, 177, 179, 177, 179, 179, 179, 179, 181, 181, 183, 183, 184, 184, 185, 185, 186, 185, 187, 186, 187, 187, 188, 185, 186, 184, 185, 183, 183, 181, 181, 179, 179, 176, 176, 174, 174, 172, 171, 170, 167, 164, 164, 162, 161, 159, 159, 156, 157, 154, 153, 152, 169, 198, 
Camera 3: 185, 187, 188, 191, 189, 190, 192, 192, 193, 193, 192, 194, 194, 194, 195, 199, 196, 196, 196, 197, 199, 198, 198, 198, 199, 199, 199, 199, 196, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 202, 203, 202, 202, 203, 203, 204, 204, 204, 203, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 205, 205, 205, 206, 206, 206, 205, 206, 206, 206, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 208, 207, 209, 209, 208, 208, 209, 209, 207, 208, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 208, 209, 209, 209, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 210, 210, 209, 209, 207, 207, 206, 206, 204, 203, 203, 201, 199, 200, 198, 195, 195, 195, 193, 167, 179, 
Runetime: 1987
```

Here it is with me using While Loops:

```
void readPixels()  
{
  digitalWrite(SI, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime/2);
  digitalWrite(CLK, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime/2);
  digitalWrite(SI, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime/2);
  digitalWrite(CLK, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime);

  int i = 0;
  while(i < 128)
  {
    i++;
    digitalWrite(CLK, HIGH);
    pixelsArray1[i]=analogRead(Cam1Aout);
    pixelsArray2[i]=analogRead(Cam2Aout);
    pixelsArray3[i]=analogRead(Cam3Aout);
    digitalWrite(CLK, LOW);
  }

  delayMicroseconds(20);

}

OUTPUT:
Camera 1: 224, 161, 172, 179, 185, 198, 199, 203, 206, 208, 208, 211, 212, 213, 214, 216, 216, 217, 217, 218, 217, 219, 219, 216, 215, 217, 220, 222, 223, 223, 224, 226, 225, 229, 231, 231, 232, 235, 235, 236, 237, 238, 240, 240, 240, 240, 241, 242, 242, 242, 242, 243, 243, 246, 248, 252, 255, 262, 266, 271, 276, 281, 287, 291, 296, 304, 307, 314, 319, 326, 332, 331, 337, 337, 335, 352, 359, 359, 359, 361, 366, 371, 371, 372, 376, 382, 384, 384, 382, 380, 380, 377, 372, 366, 361, 355, 351, 344, 339, 331, 323, 318, 312, 307, 301, 294, 290, 284, 280, 273, 268, 263, 257, 252, 248, 241, 231, 227, 219, 209, 199, 191, 182, 172, 163, 155, 147, 176, 
Camera 2: 216, 193, 196, 203, 207, 212, 216, 219, 222, 223, 227, 231, 231, 234, 236, 238, 239, 241, 242, 242, 244, 247, 247, 248, 249, 252, 252, 252, 254, 255, 258, 259, 259, 259, 260, 262, 262, 263, 263, 265, 272, 268, 267, 268, 268, 270, 270, 271, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 275, 275, 276, 276, 277, 277, 278, 277, 280, 278, 278, 277, 278, 276, 276, 275, 275, 275, 275, 276, 277, 278, 280, 282, 285, 287, 289, 291, 294, 295, 299, 301, 304, 306, 310, 312, 313, 316, 319, 319, 321, 322, 323, 323, 322, 319, 318, 315, 312, 308, 305, 302, 298, 294, 289, 284, 280, 275, 270, 263, 257, 251, 244, 238, 232, 227, 223, 216, 211, 206, 202, 197, 193, 188, 207, 
Camera 3: 0, 231, 235, 238, 240, 243, 247, 250, 252, 254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 257, 259, 260, 260, 260, 262, 260, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 268, 269, 273, 274, 276, 275, 276, 277, 278, 278, 279, 279, 280, 280, 280, 281, 281, 281, 281, 283, 283, 283, 284, 284, 285, 285, 285, 286, 286, 286, 286, 287, 289, 289, 289, 290, 291, 291, 292, 293, 293, 294, 294, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 299, 298, 297, 296, 295, 294, 294, 292, 292, 291, 290, 289, 291, 291, 290, 289, 291, 292, 295, 298, 300, 302, 304, 304, 307, 307, 307, 305, 304, 304, 303, 300, 297, 294, 289, 287, 283, 280, 275, 272, 269, 263, 259, 255, 252, 246, 241, 237, 212, 
Runetime: 1991
```

Some notes:

- I've optimized the `analogRead();` method with prescalers so they are faster than usual.
- While the output of the second code does show some difference when I hold an object in the line of site of the cameras it is a much smaller difference and only works when I'm holding it directly in front of the cameras.

Comment: If you want to further optimize the code , Use digitalWriteFast library which deals with register level toggling.

Comment: Can you give me a synopsis of why we would use digitalWriteFast instead of just digitalWrite?

Answer (score 4):

What most probably happened is the compiler decided to optimize your code and threw those `nop`'s away. You should force the compiler to keep your assembly intact by defining it `volatile`:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("nop\n\t");
```

Alternatively, you could make a delay by doing something useful, for example:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 128)
{
i++;
digitalWrite(CLK, HIGH);
pixelsArray1[i]=analogRead(Cam1Aout);
pixelsArray2[i]=analogRead(Cam2Aout);
pixelsArray3[i]=analogRead(Cam3Aout);
digitalWrite(CLK, LOW);
}
```

PS. The drop in sensitivity you are seeing may well be normal. Your datasheet says:

> The minimum integration time for any given array is determined by time required to clock out all the pixels
>   in the array and the time to discharge the pixels. The time required to discharge the pixels is a constant.
>   Therefore, **the minimum integration period is simply a function of the clock frequency** and the number of pixels
>   in the array. A slower clock speed increases the minimum integration time and reduces the maximum light level
>   for saturation on the output. The minimum integration time shown in this data sheet is based on the maximum
>   clock frequency of 8 MHz.

Since your optimized code runs faster, there is less time left for integration, which reduces the output value.

Also, try adding a delay after `digitalWrite(CLK, HIGH);` to respect the `ts` time mentioned in the waveform on page 5.

Comment: Thanks. Those are both good ideas, but I keep running into the same problem. I've posted an update with output if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: @CrystalPritzker See my edit, what you see may be normal.

Comment: So I added a Clock Prescaler to reduce the speed from 16MHz to 8MHz and that didn't change the numbers. Does this mean that the minimum integration period is not the problem?

Comment: @CrystalPritzker Yes, that most probably proves the problem is elsewhere, but honestly, I'm out of ideas. Do you have a scope to verify the timings?

Comment: I verified the timing by first blinking an LED and seeing if the delay was longer. (i.e. a `delay(1000);` command would take 2 seconds instead of one.) It's fine though, thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `digitalWrite`, it's doing a bunch of stuff behind the scenes besides setting the pin. This is necessary because Arduino conflates PWM and regular switching, and so there's an interrupt-driven background architecture that [needs managing](http://www.crash-bang.com/arduino-digital-io/). In the end, a simple pin switch using `digitalWrite` takes 100 clock cycles, [according to this fellow](https://www.baldengineer.com/digitalwrite-on-a-logic-analyzer.html). Thus your `NOP` is a drop in the timing bucket.

If you want better control over timing, lower-level AVR controls, or libraries that implement them, are what you want to use. An oscilloscope would be really handy for debugging, but otherwise you're forced to rely on mental models.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean? Why would the `NOP` affect the `digitalWrite` if the `NOP` is executed after `digitalWrite`? Don't the command execute from top to bottom or do I just not understand programming? FYI This is my first Arduino Project ever.

Comment: Before, your timing was enforced by the calls to delayMicroseconds. If you want to get down to the ~100ns timing level, you need to take into account how long functions take to execute. NOP takes one clock cycle, but digitalWrite takes way longer so it's the bigger portion of your timing. So to get the full picture, you need to consider the lower-level details. Along the same lines, the analog read takes longest of all.

Comment: I optimized by analog read and it takes a fraction of the orginal time. What I'm still confused about is how the digital write could possibly cause this problem. Are you saying that because digital write takes longer to execute that is throwing off my timing? Because I don't see how it taking longer would affect me.

Comment: My answer was more directed at why your timing might not be what you were expecting. But yes, I'm not sure how that would explain what you're seeing. I'm not familiar with the sensor you're using but I'll try to find some time to take a closer look.

Comment: If you can that would be a big help, I've been researching this problem for a couple days with no real success.